# interaction effect in linear mixed models - interpretation

Tags: interpretation, lme4-nlme, fixed-effects-model

I ran the following model:

```
test = lmer(Reaction_Time  ~  Code_IS_Condition * Code_IS_Language  + (1 + Code_IS_Condition | Subject) + (1 + Code_IS_Language |Subject) + (1 | Picture_Name) , 
data = data5[data5$PWI_Accuracy=="Hit"  & data5$PWI_Condition=="Cog" & data5$Combined_X=='0',],)
```

Reaction_Time is a continuous variable; Code_IS_Condition has 3 levels (reference level is level 3); Code_IS_language has 2 levels (reference level is level 2). Below is the effects that was generated

```
Fixed effects:
                                     Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                           972.522     33.591   20.500  28.952  < 2e-16 ***
Code_IS_Condition1                     82.336     32.042   15.800   2.570  0.02071 *  
Code_IS_Condition2                    -54.818     30.594   15.500  -1.792  0.09266 .  
Code_IS_Language1                      -9.167     12.672  233.100  -0.723  0.47018    
Code_IS_Condition1:Code_IS_Language1 -104.818     35.771  901.100  -2.930  0.00347 ** 
Code_IS_Condition2:Code_IS_Language1   55.901     35.702  905.300   1.566  0.11775
```

I interpreted the interaction effect as follows: Reaction times are shorter for Code_IS_Condition 1 than condition 3 when language is 1. However, when I compare this to the raw means, I see that condition 3 takes a shorter time. Can I request you to help?
Thanks

Comment: It might because the interaction "condition1 and lgaguage1" has an even bigger (-104.818) negative coefficient than condition1 (82.366)?

Comment: How did you calculate the "raw means" you refer on?

Answer (score 1):

For language level 2 it actually is the case that reaction times are *longer* for condition 1 than condition 3 (+82.336 units). So I assume you calculated your "raw means" given language level 1 (*scenario A*) or all data (*scenario B*). In *scenario B* your findings of a shorter reaction time in condition 3 might be due to a large percentage of condition 3 observations. In *scenario A* you might be facing the [Simpsons's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox): When conditioning on further variables, your results may change.

---

Compare how strong fixed effects estimations can change when conditioning on the identifiere variable:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
        x = 1:9,
        y = jitter(c(7:9, 4:6, 1:3)))

plot(y~x, col = ID, data = df)

round(coef(lm(y~x, data = df)), 2)# 9.14 and -0.82 
round(fixef(lmer(y~x+(1+x|ID), data =df)), 2) #-0.27 and 1.04
```